# openjscad - Javascript vector rotate to rotate by vector

Tags: javascript, openjscad

I am using https://openjscad.org/

I have two-fold question about javascript vector rotate:

```
vec=vec.rotateX(angle0);
vec=vec.rotateY(angle1);
vec=vec.rotateZ(angle2);
```

1) Does javascript rotates vectors in degrees or radians?

2) How these 3 lines would translate rotating vector by another vector?
Such as vec = vec.rotate(angle,new Vector(1,0,0))? for angle 1

3) Is there any documentation about vector rotate in javascript?
I want to understand the logic...

Comment: Who knows? It depends whatever library you're using.

Comment: Did you check the OpenJSCAD documentation and source if you want to understand the implementation? Also, I think this is more of a math question about vectors (which is independent of JavaScript)...

Comment: It is not very useful: https://openjscad.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=design_guide_rotate&s[]=rotate

Answer (score 1):

It was degrees equivalent to

Vector3d vec = new Vector3d(1.15,58.1,7.58);
vec.Rotate(Rhino.RhinoMath.ToRadians(10.4),Vector3d.XAxis);

vec.Rotate(Rhino.RhinoMath.ToRadians(15.3),Vector3d.YAxis);

vec.Rotate(Rhino.RhinoMath.ToRadians(17.7),Vector3d.ZAxis);